# Own domain for Microsoft Azure Cloud

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I don't understand how to make my own domain name for azure cloud services. I have the site on domain playnoch.cloudapp.net and have bought my own domain nochgames.ru.

I have already added:

```
CNAME record:
www.nochgames.ru.   21599   IN  CNAME   playnoch.cloudapp.net.
```

and

```
A-record: 
nochgames.ru.       21599   IN  A   40.127.194.234
```

Where did I go wrong or what didn't I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DNS entries look good, but you need to configure your nginx server appropriately.